# Accessing nginx-ingress-controller error log

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have set up one Kubernetes master node and 2 workers node. I deployed two web applications as a pod using `kubectl`. I deployed `nginx-ingress-controller` ( image: `gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.6`) and created a service for the same with nodeport option. How do I access the error logs of the `nginx-ingress-controller`? I'm able to see `error.log` under `/var/log/nginx/`, but it is link to `/dev/stderr`.

Comment: `stern` is a useful utility for this: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/10/tail-kubernetes-with-stern/

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR

```
kubectl logs -n <<ingress_namespace>> <<ingress_pod_name>>
```

Check the namespace under which the Ingress controller is currently running.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
helloworld-deployment-7dc448d6b-5zvr8   1/1     Running   1          3d20h
helloworld-deployment-7dc448d6b-82dnt   1/1     Running   1          3d20h

$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-apiserver-minikube                     1/1     Running   1          3d20h
nginx-ingress-controller-586cdc477c-rhj9z   1/1     Running   1          3d21h
```

For me, it happens to be the `kube-system` namespace on the pod `nginx-ingress-controller-586cdc477c-rhj9z`.

Now, get the logs just like you would for any pod using

```
 kubectl logs -n kube-system nginx-ingress-controller-586cdc477c-rhj9z
```

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, you will see that containerized applications spit out their logs to stdout/stderr, which means they are available as container logs. In Kubernetes you can access these logs by means of ie. `kubectl logs <pod>`

Update: a very nice tool for logs cli browsing - https://github.com/wercker/stern

Comment: Yes I did accessed the log using kubectl logs. But I hope it is only stdout logs. It has both stdout and stderr logs? Please confirm.

Comment: yep, it has both

Answer (score 1):

I prefer: `kubectl logs -lapp=nginx-ingress`

(get the logs of all pods with the label *nginx-ingress*)

Comment: `kubectl -n ingress-nginx logs -f -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx` it needs the namespaces. Nice tip.